# Elimnate the 5 newest records from consideration

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a featured page that lists records in different categories.
5 Newest, 5 Least Viewed, 5 Most Viewed..

That part is not difficult:

Newest: `SELECT TOP 5 * ORDER BY ID_Record DESC`

Least: `SELECT * FROM tbl_Name WHERE ORDER BY Hits_Field LIMIT 5`

Most: `SELECT * FROM tbl_Name WHERE ORDER BY Hits_Field DESC LIMIT 5`

Here is my question..
Because the newest records are possibly the least viewed they could feasibly show up in both queries.  I want to eliminate the 5 newest records from consideration.
How do I write a SQL Statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Name 
WHERE (NOT THE 5 NEWEST ID_Record BUT ALL OTHERS STILL IN CONSIDERATION) 
ORDER BY Hits_Field LIMIT 5
```

I know there is a NOT IN consideration, but I am new to this and need help writing a nested statement for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this could work:

```
"SELECT * from table_name where Id_Record not in (SELECT Id_Record from table_name order by Hits_Field LIMIT 5) order by Hits_Field LIMIT` 5"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_Name`
ORDER BY `Hits_Field`
LIMIT 5,5
```

[`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/select.html) actually can have two parameters: an offset and the amount of records. So if you want to drop the first 5 records and the select the next 5, use `LIMIT 5,5`.

Comment: K, originally I thought you had it.. still learned something from your post thanks for that. Problem remains that It isn't that I want to drop the first five results. I want to eliminate them if they are the five newest records in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can offset

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Name 
ORDER BY Hits_Field LIMIT 5,5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Limit parameters.

1) To eliminate Newest 5 records

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Name ORDER BY Hits_Field ASC LIMIT 5 [Parameter to display from **5** th record], 1000[Parameter to display up to 1000 record];
```

2) To eliminate Least-viewed(Oldest) 5 records

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Name ORDER BY Hits_Field DESC LIMIT 5 [Parameter to display from **5** th record], 1000[Parameter to display up to 1000 record];
```

Hope This Will Help.

Answer (score 0):

The logic would be
Grab the 10 least viewed (to have enough records to eliminate 5),
remove any that also show up in the newest (up to 5, but could be less), 
then limit that quantity to 5

Try EXCEPT or MINUS, something like

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM tbl_Name WHERE ORDER BY Hits_Field LIMIT 10
EXCEPT
SELECT TOP 5 * ORDER BY ID_Record DESC
)
LIMIT 5
```